# Dynamically update AMI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a question regarding AWS, have an AMI with windows server installed, IIS installed, and a site up and running.
My AutoScale always maintains two instances created based on this AMI.
However, whenever I need to change something on the site I need to upload a new instance, make the changes, update the AMI and update the auto-scale, which is quite time consuming.
Is there any way to automate this by linking to a Git repository?

Answer (score 0):

This is more like a CI CD work rather than achieved in AWS.

You can schedule a CI CD pipeline to detect any update happens in SCM(GIT) and trigger a build job(Jenkins or similar tool) which will provide an artifact to you. You can deploy the artifact to respective application server using CD tools (ansible/even with jenkins or similar tools) whichever suits your infra. In the deploy script itself you can connect to ec2 service to create a new AMI once  deployment is completed.

You need to use set of tools to achieve it SCM webhook/poll, Jenkins, Ansible.